# Deploying App to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, heroku

When I want to deploy my app to heroku (using git push heroku master), it gives me an error and told me to install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'. So after successfully installing that gem, I tried deploying it again to heroku and it still give me the same error!! However, I've already installed it. And now I can't even run my rails project locally (rails server). May I know what could be the cause of this?

Here's my content in database.yml file:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: did you do a bundle install? and can you post your database.yml file

Comment: yeap.. and now I got the error: "Could not find RubyGem Bundler......" This is very weird as I have been using Rails for a month now and I've not encountered any problems! :( Anyways, I've posted the dataabase.yml file in the qn

Comment: ALso, heroku uses postgres so in your gemfile put the sqlite gem in group :development do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku does not work with `SQLite3`

Open your Gemfile and replace the line:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

for

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

I also suggest you to read the heroku instructions: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks! Though now I got another problem regarding the "We're sorry, but something went wrong" Hahaha! That's another problem but thanks a lot for solving this problem! :D

Answer (score 2):

Make your gemfile look like this

```
      group :production do
         gem 'pg'
      end
      group :development, :test do
         gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
      end
```